# CRM Javascript to check invalid email format and enter exactly one email

Tags: javascript, regex, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm writing a javascript for CRM 2013 that triggers when a text field is modified. The requirement is:

1. Check when the input is invalid email address. Alert a pop up
   message.
2. Check if there is more than one email address and alert pop
   up message. Only one email address is allowed in this field.

This is my code. At first I was using separator to check the email address input list and it works. I removed the separator now for requirement #2 and it doesn't work anymore. Do I need to change the regular expression specific for just one email address?

```
function EmailTest(EmailField) {
  var Email = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+\.([a-zA-Z])+([a-zA-Z])+/;
  if (Email.test(EmailField)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function CheckEmailString(context) {
  try {
    //getting the input
    var EmailString = context.getEventSource().getValue();
    if (EmailString != null) {
      var Flag = true;

      if (!EmailTest(EmailString)) {
        Flag = false;
      }
      //}
      if (Flag != true) {
        alert("Please check if the email might contain invalid format. Note that only one email address is allowed for this.");
        //prevents users from saving the form if not valid
        //context.getEventArgs().preventDefault();
        //Xrm.Page.context.getEventArgs.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    alert(err.message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Which field are you checking? Can you start by checking for spaces or two "@" chars or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression you're currently using will test for true as long as the text box starts with a valid email address (i.e. test@example.com) - you need to include the end-of-string character `$` at the end of the expression to check that nothing else follows the match:

`/^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+\.([a-zA-Z])+([a-zA-Z])+$/;`

Further to this, the regular expression could be made a little more lean. I would suggest the following edit to achieve the same evaluation results:

`/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/;`

One further suggestion is that you trim the text in `EmailField` before you run it through the expression, as spaces or other whitespace characters at the beginning or end of the field will cause the test to fail.

Comment: Thank you! The new regex did the trick. CRM automatically trims begininng whitespace on text field so no need for additional trimming. Thanks much.